# Easier LocalStorage example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I know that there were similar question about it, but can you explain in the easiest way how I can use localStorage when the user inserts data in one page, but this data should be used in another file.

For example in registration.html we have:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="firstname"> <input type="button" value="OK" >
```

in cabinet.html I want to see:

> Hello, *inputed name*

I need to implement it using JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are tons of examples and documentation of this simple task online. What have you learned from your research? What exactly didn’t work?

Comment: localStorage is shared between pages on the same domain, use it the same way you would on any other page. See [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent) if looking an event based solution

Answer (score 0):

You have two options when it comes to client storage. LocalStorage and SessionStorage. The difference being that SessionStorage is cleared when the session closes (e.g. browser closes) whereas LocalStorage is cleared when the web browser data is cleared (e.g. cookies, etc)

**How to Use:**

```
LocalStorage.setItem("name", "John Doe");
LocalStorage.getItem("name");
SessionStorage.setItem("name", "John Doe");
SessionStorage.getItem("name");
```

These can work on any page. For example you can use 'setItem' on one page and 'getItem' on another.

**More Detail:**
[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp][1]

Answer (score 0):

**registration.html**:

```
<form id="registration-form">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="firstname" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('registration-form')
    .addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      localStorage.setItem('name', document.getElementById('firstname').value);
    });
</script>
```

**cabinet.html**:

```
<div>
  Hello, <span id="name" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('name').textContent = localStorage.getItem('name');
</script>
```

Comment: @АдольфінаБучинська did you have a chance to try this example ^^^?